# Why are there no brushless motors with more than 3 phases (6, 9, etc.)?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, torque, power, electronics

My understanding is that adding phases will (up to a point) add the ability to push more power through a motor (more Amps total, same per individual winding wire), generating more torque for similar heat output. It's a technique used for industrial applications (there are often 6 phase generators, etc.) and it was investigated for [power transmission in the US](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqZtptHnC2I)

Since high torque with low heat is such a desirable trait for brushless motors, whether in robotics or drones, why don't we see this more/ever? It isn't used for power transmission because it requires additional controllers/equipment, adding expense/complexity, so is that the reason? It seems like in a robotics context getting more torque (~2x?) would be well worth doubling the controller. Is it simply that a 6-phase motor with equivalent windings would require more copper, and that's expensive?

I think it should be possible to modify a normal motor and run it with two controllers simultaneously, but I've been unable to find any projects experimenting with this. Is there some fundamental reason why this is a bad idea that I'm not thinking about?

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly used in [windpower (generator)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228899943_Multi-phase_generators_viability_for_offshore_wind_farms_with_HVDC_transmission) applications.
On motor usage you need to have multi phase source of energy, which will destroy any economical advantage compared to multiple 3-phase motors, as the speed variations can so easily be done with inverters by varying frequency.

Yet, it might be interesting to use on Electric cars, where the Battery is DC source, but where AC is still preferred for motors (i.e. Tesla) because it's advances on varying loads and zero speed starts.

So is it possible? YES.
Maybe it's just not yet used only because of historical reasons.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any thoughts on why only generators use this technique?